# How to tackle memory error while loading heavy CSV Files

Tags: python, csv, numpy, image-processing

I made a CSV file to store some data like this:

```
img = loadmat('test.mat')
a,b,c = np.shape(img)  # c is the no. of slices
for i in range(c):
    feature_1 = #kurtosis of image slice
    feature_2 = #entropy of image slice
    .
    .
    feature_8 = #skewness of image slice
    train_data = np.concatenate((feature_1,feature_2,...,feature_8),axis=1)
    #this loop will repeat for all the slices and result will be appended in another array
    train_data01.append(train_data)
    #this will give a list with all data in one axis.
feature_img = np.concatenate(train_data01,axis=0)
#this will give a array of size (mx8) where m is the number of pixels in image.
np.savetxt('savedata.csv',feature_img,fmt = '%4.2f') #save teh data in csv file
```

Now I tried to retrieve the data back like this:

```
hg01 = []
with open('savedata.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        hg01.append(row)

hg01 = np.concatenate(hg01, axis = 0)
hg01_feature = np.empty(shape=(np.shape(hg01)[0],80), dtype='float32')

for i in range(np.shape(hg01)[0]):
     a = hg01[i]
     b = np.fromstring(a,dtype='float32',sep=' ')
     np.append(np.transpose(hg01_feature[i,:]),b,axis=1)
```

Now the problem is the actual dimension of numpy array of hg01 is 1520640x80 which is ~644MB in size. Now after 6th patient my system get down and while loading 7th patient data it shows memory error at the following line:

```
hg07 = np.concatenate(hg07, axis = 0)
```

So guys I have around 40 patient data and how to load this data.
I am working for image classification with Random Forest. My system has 8 GB Ram.

Comment: `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt` can usually handle CSV files such as those written by `np.savetxt`.

Comment: Don't use `np.append` (like that).

Comment: @hpaulj: Can you suggest any other method in answer (and with example also). Thanks

Comment: If you have memory errors during load, you'll also have them during processing.

Comment: @hpaulj: That's right. but what is the solution. How to tackle this huge data.Can you tell me if I down sample a numpy array does it affects its information content and how to do it(if possible.).

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your rows is a single string.  I think you can get the behavior you want by splitting each string.  The splitting is a little complicated because I was only approximately right: Each row is actually a one-element list holding a single string, so you have to deference the [0] element.  The splitting should look something like this:

```
new_feature = [ f[0].split() for f in feature ]
```

Now do np.shape on new_feature and hopefully that will give what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I did by some different way. Now the problem is every numpy array is too big i.e. 1520640x80 which is ~644MB in size and after loading 6th patient data numpy shows memory error during 7th patient data loading. Can you tell me how to tackle with huge data and that memory error.

Comment: Better to add code to your question.  It's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: @hpaulj: OK.Let me make some changes in the question to mention the current problem.